# NameError: name 'uuid' is not defined in BigQueryML Tutorial

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm getting started in BigQueryML, and trying to get [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/bigqueryml-ncaa?authuser=2) done. The problem I am running into is when I try to add this line of code (Found at Step One Part 15):

```
dataset_id = "bqml_tutorial_{}".format(str(uuid.uuid4().hex))
```

I get the error

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1746232870d0> in <module>()
      3 # other invocations of this tutorial.  In practice, you could leverage
      4 # a persistent dataset and not create/destroy it with each invocation.
----> 5 dataset_id = "bqml_tutorial_{}".format(str(uuid.uuid4().hex))

NameError: name 'uuid' is not defined
```

I've tried to use `from uuid import UUID` but haven't had any luck.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you `import uuid`?

Comment: Yes, I used `from uuid import UUID`.

Comment: @DerekFisher So you didn't import the module `uuid`, you imported just the class `UUID`. I.e., `uuid` is not defined

Comment: But you are trying to use `uuid4`, not `UUID`. So you should maybe do `from uuid import uuid4` but the way you are currently trying to call it simply requires `import uuid`

Comment: The code is written assuming you did `import uuid`, not `from uuid import UUID`. Once you `import uuid`, all of its classes, functions and variables are available via `uuid.whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

You imported `UUID` specifically, which is a specific class that you can instantiate, but is not the uuid4 function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.UUID

If you want to use [`uuid4()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/uuid.html#uuid.uuid4), you have to actually import it, since it's separate from the `UUID` class:

```
from uuid import uuid4
print(uuid4())
# output: 0e18abd8-8470-48ef-be58-6bc34eea7548
```

This question could've probably been avoided by looking at the official `uuid` documentation. That's always a good place to start when troubleshooting.